# Only lint typescript when saving file in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

By default VSCode validates the typescript sources while editing them. Is it possible to somehow change this to only validate the sources when the files is saved? This is possible with ESLint but I cannot seem to find how to changes this for Typescript.

Comment: Is `editor.formatOnType` option enabled in your settings (workspace or user) ? And to format on save only activate `editor.formatOnSave` option

Comment: `editor.formatOnType` is disabled, but I'm not sure if this is really the correct settings. It is about the validation of Typescript that would show problems.

Comment: You can desactivate vscode native typescript validation, in the settings section search for `Typescript Validate` and uncheck it

Comment: If you want to do this you have to desactivate native validation and use your own via eslint. Eslint has an option `Eslint: Run` where you can choose between `onSave` and `onType`, vscode doesn't have an equivalent option for typescript validation

Comment: This is not an option. I use eslint but this has nothing to do with the validation TypeScript is doing. All the type checking and a lot more can only be done with typescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of VS Code 1.41, there is no VS Code setting for this. [Here is a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81737)

As a workaround:

1. Disable live TypeScript validation by setting `"typescript.validate.enable": false`
2. Create a [TypeScript watch task](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) in VS Code for your tsconfig project. Make sure it has a problem matcher. Here's an example watch task definition:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558 
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "typescript",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
            "option": "watch",
            "problemMatcher": [
                {
                    "base": "$tsc-watch",
                    "applyTo": "allDocuments"
                }
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

3. Start the watch task.

Tasks will only revalidate the file when they are saved to disk (this also means stale errors will stick around until you save the file)